# I'm addicted to watch movies

Tags: grammar

I'm addicted to watch movies.

I'm addicted watching movies.

Which one is correct? And if they're both wrong, can someone explain how to properly use " I'm addicted" and "I'm addicted to" in a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Both "I'm addicted to watch movies" and "I'm addicted watching movies" are incorrect. The correct sentence would be: "I'm addicted **to watching** movies."

The phrase **to be addicted to [thing]** takes a noun (to be addicted to *heroin*) or a gerund (to be addicted to *biking*). A gerund is sometimes called a *nounal verb* to emphasize the fact that it acts as a noun in a sentence but it is describing an action.

Comment: I thought after "to" we need to use verb without "ing".

Comment: @EraserHead you're correct when talking about *a verb itself*, but *watching* is a noun, even though it's based on a verb. The phrase here is **to be addicted to** and then a noun, for example *drugs* which is a noun, or *watching* which is also a noun. The **to** used in this case is not the same **to** used in the infinitive form of a verb.

Comment: "I'm addicted to dance" is wrong                                      "I'm addicted to dancing" is correct?

Comment: @EraserHead "I'm addicted to dancing" is correct. But "I'm addicted to dance" can *also* be correct because "dance" is a noun—you could be specific and say "I'm addicted to ballet" or more general and say "I'm addicted to dance." (But this is only because "dance" is a noun that is the thing the verb "to dance" refers to. "Watch" is a noun meaning "a small clock worn on the wrist" and has nothing to do with the verb "to watch.")